# how to find if the user has completed typing on an edittext view

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, typing

I would want to find if the user has completed typing in an `edittext` and if yes then remove the `focussable` from that component. I have tried implementing a `TextWatcher()` and overridden the `onTextChanged()`, `beforeTextChanged()` and `afterTextChanged()` but then im not sure how i would know if the user i/p is complete. Once the user i/p is complete i want to set its `focusable` to false (`text.setFocusable(false)`).

I understand that `afterTextChanged()` gets invoked everytime the user adds a character to the `edittext` view.

```
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // component.setValue(s.toString());
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // Do nothing.
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // Do nothing.
  }
});
```

I want to set the value to the component only once the user i/p is complete.

Comment: what is the condition of user i/p to complete? as in number of characters or time of last input??

Comment: If user i/p is completed he will press "done" or "next" .Or put a button to complete.

Comment: He would press the done. But this edittext is in a class in itself (de-serializing a component tree) and would not know if the user says done. The issue is that when the user clicks a button, the focus change listener on the edit text is not invoked.

Comment: i think u can fire keyboard's done and do whatever u want.

Comment: The question is when would i fire that ?